# [Age in days]how to convert posix time to datetime and subtract from current time to get the age?

Tags: python, datetime

I am trying to convert posix time to datetime to subtract from current time  to get the age in days and running into below error?any guidance on how to achieve this?

```
import time
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import date

gerrit_last_updated_time = date.fromtimestamp(1551045234)
current_time = datetime.now()

print gerrit_last_updated_time
print current_time

age =  current_time - gerrit_last_updated_time
```

Error:-

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "convert_epochtime_time.py", line 11, in <module>
    age =  current_time - gerrit_last_updated_time
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'datetime.datetime' and 'datetime.date'
```

Comment: If you're doing `from datetime import datetime`, you don't need to call `datetime.datetime()`.  Just use `datetime()`.

Comment: @JohnGordon - If I just use datetime I get the error `TypeError: Required argument 'month' (pos 2) not found`

Comment: I think you want the `fromtimestamp()` or `utcfromtimestamp()` functions, not the `datetime()` function.

Comment: @JohnGordon - I tried and updated my question with it,it stil throws the erorr shown

Comment: Don't use `date.fromtimestamp`, use `datetime.fromtimestamp`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to compare a `date` object with a `datetime` object, and `datetime.fromtimestamp` takes seconds, so you will also need to divide by 1000 to convert milliseconds. For example:

```
from datetime import datetime

ts = datetime.fromtimestamp(1551045234 / 1000)
now = datetime.now()
age_in_days =  now - ts
```